# mysql.slow.log is not created even though it's configured in /etc/my.cnf , what could be the reason?

Tags: centos, mysql, logging

This is the relevant section from `/etc/my.cnf`:

```
[mysqld]
slow-query-log            = ON
long_query_time           = 2
log_slow_queries          = /var/log/mysql-slow.log
```

The problem is that file is missing and even if I `touch` it , nothing get written there.
I've tried changing the log location to `$datadir/mysql-slow.log` and in the `/etc/my.cnf` file it looks like this:

```
log_slow_queries          = mysql-slow.log
```

I've forgot to mention that the user and owner of the `mysql-slow.log` file are mysql.
But it doesn't work as well, any idea how to fix it?

```
[root@dbsrv ~]# grep slow /etc/my.cnf 
slow-query-log              = ON
log_slow_queries            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log 
slow-query-log              = ON
log_slow_queries            = /var/log/mysql/slow.log
[root@dbsrv ~]# ll /var/log/mysql/slow.log ; ll /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql 0 2014-02-04 18:23 /var/log/mysql/slow.log
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql 0 2014-02-04 18:23 /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
[root@dbsrv ~]#
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using ???

Comment: I use MYSQL version 5.5.33 .

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be present and writeable by the mysqld uid *when mysqld starts up*, hence:

```
# touch /var/log/mysql-slow.log
# chown mysql /var/log/mysql-slow.log
# /etc/init.d/mysqld restart
```

(or, instead of restarting the server, you can do mysqladmin -u root flush-logs)

If it's still not writing to the file, check that you do actually have slow queries! And look at the MySQL error log for clues.

Comment: I cannot restart the mysqld service as I'm concerned it will drop replication but I tried `mysqladmin -u root flush-logs` and `service mysqld reload` but it still doesn't write to the log...